# Trying to understand a mem leak

Tags: c++

I'm working with VLD (Visual Leak Detector), and it detects some mem leaks. I'm trying to understand why this is a mem leak for VLD. It could be a false positive?

The code is very simple:

```
    CGlobalLog* CGlobalLog::m_instance=NULL;  //static instance
    CGlobalLog::CGlobalLog()
    {
        minimiumLogLevel = LOGLEVEL_INFO;   
    }

    CGlobalLog::~CGlobalLog(void)
    {
        if(m_instance != NULL)
            delete m_instance;
    }

            // this method is static
    CGlobalLog& CGlobalLog::getInstance()
    {

        if(m_instance == NULL){
            m_instance = new CGlobalLog();
        }
        return *m_instance;

    }
```

Where `LOGLEVEL` is an enum and m_instance is `CGlobalLog* CGlobalLog::m_instance`.
The trace is:

```
WARNING: Visual Leak Detector detected memory leaks!
---------- Block 504 at 0x009B2290: 92 bytes ----------
  Call Stack:
    c:\users\ferran\directo\gameprojects2008\zeleste2d\src\log\globallog.cpp (26): LogSystem_v2.exe!glog::CGlobalLog::getInstance + 0x7 bytes
    c:\users\ferran\directo\gameprojects2008\zeleste2d\src\log\globallog.cpp (235): LogSystem_v2.exe!glog::CGlobalLog::exposeAPI
    c:\users\ferran\directo\gameprojects2008\games_and_samples\logsystem_v2\src\main.cpp (47): LogSystem_v2.exe!main + 0xB bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (586): LogSystem_v2.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x19 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (403): LogSystem_v2.exe!mainCRTStartup
    0x767D339A (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 bytes
    0x774D9ED2 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 bytes
    0x774D9EA5 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36 bytes
  Data:
    00 00 00 00    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    28 23 9B 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ....(#.. ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    B0 23 9B 00    00 00 00 00    01 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     .#...... ........
    CD CD CD CD    00 CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    00 00 00 00    0F 00 00 00                    ........ ........
```

I couldn't find any reason for a mem leak.... could you helpme, please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: As an aside, the statment `if(m_instance != NULL) delete m_instance;` is equivalent to, and should (IMHO) be replaced by the shorter statement `delete m_instance;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all... How do you imagine to destructor get called? Do you call anywhere something that will destroy your object?

Secondly calling delete pointer in destructor will cause call of another destructor of same object. So you have recursive destructor call in here. As it is singleton class your call can be simply replaced with `delete this;`. You should only set m_instance to NULL, so another call of getInstance will not reference to freed memory.

Solution? write static method "deleteInstance" that will check if m_instance is not null and call delete, on m_instance and set it back to null. Then you should call i.e. at end of main function `CGlobalLog::deleteInstance();`. This way you will supress this memory leak

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you never actually create a local `CGlobalLog` because you're always using the pointer returned by `GetInstance`, so the destructor never gets called. In this case it's a good thing, since you really don't want to delete your static instance until the program is finished. You'll need to make an explicit call to delete the instance member at the end of the program.

Answer (score 1):

I response myself. Shame of me!! Sometimes I only need to explain the problem to find the solution. m_instance is never deleted because destructor is private, so it's a leak.

Comment: That's not quite the explanation. If there were a situation where the destructor should be called but couldn't, you'd get a compile error.

Comment: @Killrazor: Mmm... I don't think this is the problem, but anyway, if your change worked, nice. Note also that you should be initializing `m_instance` to NULL.

Comment: @David: Yes, you may be right `m_instance` is static, and makes sense too. Just don't know where to get that information from the question :)

Comment: @Killrazor: Your explanation is totally bogus. Private-ness of the destructor makes absolutely no difference in issues like this. In fact, it looks like your `CGlobalLog` is instantiated as a global/static object, which means that with private destructor it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Editing code. This is part of a singleton. This complements my explanation, I thought.

Comment: Here is "another" good reference for singleton: http://www.research.ibm.com/designpatterns/pubs/ph-jun96.txt

Answer (score 1):

The constructor `CGlobalLog::CGlobalLog()` has to initialize `m_instance` to NULL. Note that if not, the results are undefined (maybe memory loss, or an invalid `delete`).

Answer (score 0):

There is a race condition in `CGlobalLog::getInstance()` which could result in `CGlobalLog` objects being leaked. Imagine two threads A and B call `CGlobalLog::getInstance()` "at the same time". Thread A checks `m_instance`, determines that it is not `NULL`, and then prepares to construct a new `CGlobalLog` object. But before the call to `new` begins, the OS switches to Thread B. Thread B checks that `m_instance` is not `NULL`, constructs a new `CGlobalLog` object, and assigns it to `m_instance`. The OS might then switch to Thread A. Thread A, continuing where it left off, also constructs a new `CGlobalLog` object and assigns it to `m_instance`, thus leaking the instance allocated by Thread B.

Another possible cause of the problem is that the `CGlobalLog` destructor deletes `m_instance` if it is not `NULL`. When the object being deleted *is* the `CGlobalLog` object pointed to by `m_instance`, then the object is doubly-deleted.